# How do I get Eclipse Deployment Assembly to add a jar instead of a war from a dynamic web project

Tags: jakarta-ee, jar, war

I have two dynamic web projects and need to reference one in the deployment assembly of the other.  The problem is that it adds a .war file to WEB-INF/lib instead of a .jar which causes my tomcat server to have class not found errors.

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Java Project and include it into both of the Dynamic web app projects that you currently have.  Move the code that you want to share from web app project A with web app project B into the Java Project.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.  There is no such thing as a java class library project.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but giving solution.
Go to project properties->Project Facets-> Untick "Dynamic Web Module".